# Get RGB value opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am loading an image into python e.g.

```
image = cv2.imread("new_image.jpg")
```

How can i acccess the RGB values of `image`?

Comment: it does, but if i want to access the image rgb values how could this be done?

Comment: is it a range from 0x000000 to 0xFFFFFF? you will probably need to convert it to hex to have a recognizable color ... and then take each r,g,b value from that (it might be a range of 0.0-1.0 in which case multiply by 0xFFFFFF (the max RGB Hex)

Comment: OpenCV has excellent [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html).

Comment: @RoryLester you can use `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCbCr)` to convert your image easily, and it's probably more efficient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do

```
image[y, x, c]
```

or equivalently `image[y][x][c]`.

and it will return the value of the pixel in the `x,y,c` coordinates. Notice that indexing begins at `0`. So, if you want to access the third BGR (note: not RGB) component, you must do `image[y, x, 2]` where `y` and `x` are the line and column desired.

Also, you can get the methods available in Python for a given object by typing `dir(<variable>)`. For example, after loading `image`, run `dir(image)` and you will get some usefull commands:

```
'cumprod', 'cumsum', 'data', 'diagonal', 'dot', 'dtype', 'dump', 'dumps', 'fill',
'flags', 'flat', 'flatten', 'getfield', 'imag', 'item', 'itemset', 'itemsize', 
'max', 'mean', 'min', ...
```

Usage: `image.mean()`

Comment: `image[x, y, z]` also works, since this is just a numpy array.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to ask, i am converting an image from rgb to ycbcr and i am looping though each pixel and changing it accordingly. The process is quite intensive and takes a few seconds even on small 200x200 images. Is there another aproach to this to enhance performance? perhaps you know.

Comment: I think NumPy can perform matrix multiplications through `dot(a,b)`. Instead of accessing each element, maybe you could use it.

Comment: I was having a lot of trouble with this - it turned out the x and y values for my image were reversed. I ended up having to access the pixel values as `image[y][x]`.

Comment: @Chris, I've just changed it. Reversing the convention for `x` and `y` was very misleading... Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 10):

**Get B G R color value of pixel in Python using opencv**

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
color = int(image[300, 300])
# if image type is b g r, then b g r value will be displayed.
# if image is gray then color intensity will be displayed.
print color
```

**output:**

```
[ 73  89 102]
```

Comment: this now returns `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
`

Answer (score 5):

This code will print the red , green and blue value of pixel 300, 300:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
b,g,r = (img1[300, 300])
print (r)
print (g)
print (b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Below works.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("new_image.jpg")

color = image[y, x]

blue = int(color[0])
green = int(color[1])
red = int(color[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me well :

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np  
  
cap = cv2.imread('/home/PATH/TO/IMAGE/IMG_0835.jpg')
#You're free to do a resize or not, just for the example
cap = cv2.resize(cap, (340,480))
for x in range (0,340,1):
    for y in range(0,480,1):
        color = cap[y,x]
        print color
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easiest way to get RGB of an image is use `cv2.imshow("windowName",image)`.
The image would display with window, and the little information bar also display coordinate (x,y) and RGB below image. Like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0BC7.png). You are allowed to use mouse to see the RGB of any pixel you want.

Code example:

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("new_image.jpg")
try:
    cv2.imshow("windowName",image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
except:
    print("No this image")
```