# How to convert Hexadecimal or RGB to XY coordinates on a rectangular graph?

Tags: python, colors, coordinates, rgb

Okay, so I've been trying to graph points that correspond to RGB or Hexadecimal color values so the points are placed on the correct color on here:
[image: Color Chart]

The coordinates range X: [-240, 240] and Y: [107, -105]

How would I use python to evaluate the X and Y values?

Comment: There are only 100,000+ pixels in your range. 24 bit RGB colour space includes more than 16 million colours.

Comment: I'm just wanting to the nearest whole number, nothing exact

Comment: I know that OpenCV can do this. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187354/get-rgb-value-opencv-python). The Library PIL looks like it will do the same as well. Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/138260/2687966)

Comment: It's not that there are gaps between the colors, it's that there are whole groups of colors that don't have anything close. Where are the grays for example?

Comment: @MarkRansom This is 'not counting' greys. This is for a display of statistics using colors in the range above

Comment: So you're saying that if a color isn't in the image you provided, it won't be passed to you?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes