# How can I read rgb or hsv values of image on python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to read rgb or hsv values of a some image.
I looked it up how to read it and I found a answer.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
color = int(image[300, 300])
# if image type is b g r, then b g r value will be displayed.
# if image is gray then color intensity will be displayed.
print color
```

link: [Get RGB value opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187354/get-rgb-value-opencv-python)

but that code gave me an error like this:
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

how can I fix this error? 
thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python)

Comment: For RGB images...

The error message explains itself. The `image[300, 300]` is a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Not an integer.

You can try changing the `color = int(image[300, 300])` to `color = image[300, 300]` and then try printing the `color` directly or printing `type(color)`.

Your code might work for grayscale imaged (not tested this myself).

HTH

Comment: Add `import numpy as np` at the top, then add `color = np.array(image)` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is almost right except for the third line
Fixing removing the int function will result in the result you are looking for.

Code example

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
color = image[300,300]
print(color)
```

Result:

```
[ 95  92 101]
```

Here i got 3 number each representing the RGB space.