# Find the coordinates in an image where a specified colour is detected

Tags: python, image-processing, colors

I'm trying to make a program which takes in an image and looks throughout the image to find a colour, lets say blue, and give out the coordinates of that point in the image which has that colour.

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187354/get-rgb-value-opencv-python) seems your solution. Please make a good search before asking a question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In order to do so, you need a few pieces of information, including the height and width of the image in pixels, as well as the colormap of the image. I have done something similar to this before, and I used PIL (Pillow) to extract the color values of each individual pixel. Using this method, you should be able to reformat the pixel colour values into a two-dimensional array (array[x][y], where x is the x-coordinate and y is the y-coordinate, for easy comparison) and compare the individual pixel values with a specified RGB value.

If you have an image of unknown height and width, you could do the following to obtain the image height and width:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('path/to/file.jpg')
width, height = image.size
```

After this, you can use the following to get the pixel color values in RGB format in a list:

```
pixval = list(image.getdata())

temp = []
hexcolpix = []
for row in range(0, height, 1):
    for col in range(0, width, 1):
        index = row*width + col
        temp.append(pixval[index])
    hexcolpix.append(temp)
    temp = []
```

You can then do a comparison to find pixels that match your specified colour

Answer (score 15):

You can do that very simply with Numpy which is what underpins most image processing libraries in Python, such as **OpenCV**, or **skimage**, or **Wand**. Here I'll do it with **OpenCV**, but you could equally use any of the above or PIL/Pillow.

Using this image which has a blue line on the right side:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Define the blue colour we want to find - remember OpenCV uses BGR ordering
blue = [255,0,0]

# Get X and Y coordinates of all blue pixels
Y, X = np.where(np.all(im==blue,axis=2))

print(X,Y)
```

Or, if you want them zipped into a single array:

```
zipped = np.column_stack((X,Y))
```

---

If you prefer to use PIL/Pillow, it would go like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load image, ensure not palettised, and make into Numpy array
pim = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')
im  = np.array(pim)

# Define the blue colour we want to find - PIL uses RGB ordering
blue = [0,0,255]

# Get X and Y coordinates of all blue pixels
Y, X = np.where(np.all(im==blue,axis=2))

print(X,Y)
```

Comment: Using numpy with PIL, it appears this returns Y,X not X,Y: `X,Y = np.where(np.all(im==blue,axis=2))`

Comment: @Lukus Yes, thank you. I have edited the correction into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just noting a problem on the answer by Mark Setchell.
The X and Y coords are returned the other way around so  `X,Y = np.where(np.all(im==blue,axis=2))` changes to  `Y,X = np.where(np.all(im==blue,axis=2))`, this may just be a glitch I have though.

Comment: Mark also answerwed using PIL. You answer seems to be redundant.

Comment: @SivaShanmugam I added the try/except and changed the order of x,y variable allocation

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It would be nice if you also exlpain why code acts likes that when you changed the order of X and Y.

Comment: why the code acts like what? when I tested the code it returned y before x, so it was off the screen often. that might have been a glitch though. I just did some more testing and realised that the error was turned up because of the x,y being the wrong way around, so this answer is not very useful s have changed it.